Drawing n boxes in a row
I would like to draw identical boxes in one row.
The following error message is shown:
in {0,1,...,\bn -1}{\bc = (\bl /2+\i *(\bw +\bd ):0); \draw [draw=dbl\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@math@parse@afterindex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.25 

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

But I can't find any missing bracket.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth={18.4cm},textheight={26cm},columnsep={0.6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{53,107,186}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{%
    \bn = 5;                                    % number of boxes
    \bl = 0.05cm;                               % box line width
    \bd = 0.5cm;                                % box distance
    \bh = 4cm;                                  % box height
    \bw = (\linewidth-\bl-(\bn-1)*\bd)/\bn;     % box width
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\bn-1}{%
    \bc = (\bl/2+\i*(\bw+\bd):0);               % box coordinates
    \draw[draw=dblue,line width=\bl] \bc rectangle ++(\bw,\bh);
    };
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show the first error message you got and show it in your question ...

The messages are: no PDF, Runaway argument?, and Emergency stop.

The LaTeX error should be Paragraph ended before \tikz@math@parse@afterindex was complete. in line 25 …

I don't think you can have regular TikZ commands (\foreach, \draw, etc.) inside the \tikzmath command.

I've learned a lot about TikZ and TikZ math, when I've tried to analyze all the mistakes in the code and also while trying to find valid solutions. So for me this question was very useful.

There are several issues with your code:

You cannot use \foreach inside \tikzmath. You should instead use for to build such loops inside \tikzmath.
Your dimension calculation is wrong. The default variable type in \tikzmath is real. A value 1cm would be “converted” into pt and the pt would be cut of to get the real. But the default TikZ unit is already cm. So, e.g., just remove all the cm, but divide \linewidth by 1cm to get the correct real values.
To be able to use \draw inside \tikmath you need extra braces.

This results, e.g., in
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth={18.4cm},textheight={26cm},columnsep={0.6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{53,107,186}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{%
    int \bn;
    \bn = 5;                                    % number of boxes
    \bl = 0.05;                            % box line width
    \bd = 0.5;                             % box distance
    \bh = 4;                                % box height
    \bw = (\linewidth/1cm-\bl-\bd*(\bn-1))/\bn;     % box width
    for \i in {0,1,...,\bn-1} {
      \bc = \bl/2 + (\bw+\bd)*\i;
      {
        \draw[dblue,line width=\bl] (\bc,0) rectangle ++(\bw,\bh) % node { \bc }
        ;
      };
    };
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


Note: I've added the (commented) node { \bc } for debugging. If you remove the % you can see the value of \bc.
An alternative would be to do the \tikzmath before using \foreach and \draw. But note, that in this case, you cannot use \bn-1 as limit. So in the following example, I'm calculating one more helper variable:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth={18.4cm},textheight={26cm},columnsep={0.6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{53,107,186}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{%
    int \bn;
    int \bnn;
    \bn = 5;                                    % number of boxes
    \bl = 0.05;                            % box line width
    \bd = 0.5;                             % box distance
    \bh = 4;                                % box height
    \bw = (\linewidth/1cm-\bl-\bd*(\bn-1))/\bn;     % box width
    \bnn = \bn-1;
  }
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\bnn} {
    \tikzmath{ \bc = \bl/2 + (\bw+\bd)*\i; }
    \draw[dblue,line width=\bl] (\bc,0) rectangle ++(\bw,\bh) % node { \bc }
    ;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}

The result is the same as shown above.
If you want \bc to be a coordinate instead of the x-value only, you should declare the value type of \bc and you would also need to use extra braces in the calculation:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth={18.4cm},textheight={26cm},columnsep={0.6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{53,107,186}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{%
    int \bn;
    int \bnn;
    \bn = 5;                                    % number of boxes
    \bl = 0.05;                            % box line width
    \bd = 0.5;                             % box distance
    \bh = 4;                                % box height
    \bw = (\linewidth/1cm-\bl-\bd*(\bn-1))/\bn;     % box width
    \bnn = \bn-1;
  }
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\bnn} {
    \tikzmath{
      coordinate \bc;
      \bc = ({\bl/2 + (\bw+\bd)*\i},0);% use {…} for the calculation
    }
    \draw[dblue,line width=\bl] (\bc) rectangle ++(\bw,\bh) % node { \bc }
    ;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


you can try
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth={18.4cm},textheight={26cm},columnsep={0.6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{53,107,186}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\bn{5}
    \newdimen\bl
    \newdimen\bd
    \newdimen\bh
    \newdimen\bw
    \newdimen\bc
    \bl = 0.05cm
    \bd = 0.5cm
    \bh = 4cm
    \bw = \dimexpr (\linewidth-\bl-\bd*(\bn-1)) / \bn \relax
    \foreach[parse = true] \i in {0,1,..., \bn - 1}{%
        \bc = \dimexpr \bl/2 + (\bw+\bd)*\i \relax
        \draw[draw=dblue,line width=\bl] (0:\the\bc) rectangle ++(\bw,\bh);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}



Note: It is not recommended to use \newdimen inside a tikzpicture because the allocation would be done globally. Therefore you would allocate new registers in every tikzpicture you are using such a construct. Therefore allocation of registers usually should be done in the document preamble only. Also note: With more or less up-to-date LaTeX you can use \dimeval{…} instead of \dimexpr …\relax. See ltnews35.pdf or usrguide.pdf, section 5 for more information.

@ljguo Thank you for your solution. I have two questions: In (0:\the\bc) rectangle ++(\bw,\bh) - why do I need \the in front of \bc, but not in front of \bw and \bh? And why is [parse=true] neccessary in the foreach loop. The loops in cabohah's solutions also include calculationts, but don't use [parse=true].

@cabohah Thank you very much for your detailed explanations. They are very helpful, as I am just starting with LaTeX.

@Thomas You don't need the \the. parse=true is needed, because \bc=\dimexpr …\relax is not \tikzmath{…}. Don't forget, in my first example, we are already inside a \tikzmath. In my other examples, there are explicit \tikzmath for the calculation inside the loop. And no, you cannot use \tikzmath instead of using parse=true in ljguo's code, because of using dimension registers and \dimexpr. These are not TikZ constructs.

A variant of @cabohah's answer that uses high-level macros for parsing expressions.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth={18.4cm},textheight={26cm},columnsep={0.6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{53,107,186}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bn{5}                                    % number of boxes
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bl{0.05}                               % box line width
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bd{0.5}                                % box distance
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bh{4}                                  % box height
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bw{(\linewidth/1cm-\bl-\bd*(\bn-1))/\bn}     % box width
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \bc using {\bl/2+ (\i-1)*(\bw+\bd)}]in {1,...,\bn}{%
    \draw[draw=dblue,line width=\bl] (\bc,0) rectangle ++(\bw,\bh);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


